# Tabexpansion function Does Not Resolve Variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I'm attempting to override and implement my own TabExpansion. In the function I want to parse the contents of $psise.CurrentFile.Editor.Text when a certain $lastword criteria is matched. The issue I have is that the variable $psise.CurrentFile.Editor.Text is resolved to the contents of my TabExpansion function rather than whatever text is in a PowerShell ISE tab.

Here's simple test function. Open an ISE tab and paste the following tabexpansion function definition:

```
function tabexpansion
{ $psise.CurrentFile.Editor.Text }
```

Run the script in ISE. Next open another tab in ISE type some text and press the tab key
The output will be

```
function tabexpansion
{ $psise.CurrentFile.Editor.Text }
```

Rather than whatever text was in the second tab. Is there any way to get $psise.CurrentFile.Editor.Text to resolve at runtime when used within a tabexpansion function?

Comment: That's whack. You should file a bug on connect, regardless of whether you find a workaround :-/

Comment: It doesn't even work to do:  function tabexpansion { (Get-Variable psise).Value.CurrentFile.Editor.Text }

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what's going on there, but they are somehow executing that tabexpansion function in a bizarre frozen context.  Even doing this doesn't help:  function get-text { $psise.CurrentFile.Editor.Text } function tabexpansion { get-text } ... get-text works correctly if you run it by hand. But when you hit tab, you always get whatever you got the last time you ran get-text by hand, regardless of what file tab is open.

Comment: The odd thing is that "normal" variables seem to work OK. For example function tabexpansion { $a } if I set $a to a value I get back the value whenever I press tab key. When I set $a to some other value it correctly returns the value.

Comment: Filed a Connect bug. Please vote:
https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/551925/tabexpansion-function-does-not-resolve-variable-correctly

Comment: Should it be marked as answered with the connect bug link?

Comment: Wondering if there is a workaround. Can eventing help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this appears to be bug in PowerShell ISE. A Microsoft Connect item has been filed.